# Python, Pandas Dataframe - How to add a maximum amount of columns generated by an API?

Tags: python, pandas, api, dataframe

I am using an API that generates x amount of columns based on how many years the data has existed. Sometimes the data is 30 columns long and I would like to add a maximum number of columns generated by the API (pandas dataframe)

edit: I want the maximum to be 8 columns so the year interval is 2019-2011

[dataframe looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShp7.png)

```
   stonkticker = input().upper()
   api_key ="
   income_statement_annually = fa.income_statement(stonkticker, api_key, 
   period="annual")

   df = pd.DataFrame(income_statement_annually)
   df
```

Comment: To clarify, the API is returning a dataframe and you want to keep the final 30 columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a [tour] and post you coding efforts here as a [mre].

Comment: I want the maximum to be 8 columns

Comment: Yes, but which 8? You mentioned it's years of data - so, latest 8 years? or first 8 years? or any other logic you are thinking of? You need to add that into your questions. Better yet, show an example of how your data looks before and after

Comment: latest 8 years :D, edited and added a picture